# How to find the inverse laplace transform of an arbitrary function

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

How to find $$\mathcal{L^{-1}} \left[ \frac{F(s)}{s+a} \right]$$where $F(s)$ is the Laplace transform of $f(t).$

Comment: The title is seriously misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know about convolution, this is just a piece of cake.

$\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{F(s)}{s+a}\right\}$

$=\mathcal L^{-1}\left\{\dfrac{1}{s+a}\right\}*\mathcal L^{-1}\{F(s)\}$

$=e^{-at}*f(t)$

$=\int_0^te^{-a(t-\tau)}f(\tau)~d\tau$

$=e^{-at}\int_0^te^{a\tau}f(\tau)~d\tau$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

You know that $$\mathcal{L}(f*g)=F(s)G(s)$$ so $$\mathcal{L^{-1}}\big(F(s)G(s)\big)=f*g$$ wherein $f*g=\int_0^tf(\kappa)g(t-\kappa)d\kappa$.

Comment: Great hint! + 1

Comment: @Thanks. I hope I do well for to day at M.S.E.

Comment: You're doing well for MSE!

Answer (score 1):

Use laplace transform properties :
$$  G(s)=\frac{F(s)}{s+a} $$
$$  \mathcal{L^{-1}}[G(s)]=g(t)  $$
$$  \mathcal{L} \left[ e^{at}g(t) \right] = G(s-a)=\frac{F(s-a)}{s}  $$
$$  \frac{1}{s} \triangleq  \int_0^t   $$
$$  e^{at}g(t)=\int_0^t e^{a \tau }f( \tau ) d \tau $$
$$  g(t)=e^{-at} \int_0^t e^{a \tau }f( \tau ) d \tau $$
or we can write :
$$  g(t)= \int_0^t e^{-a(t- \tau) }f( \tau ) d \tau $$

Comment: Nice approach +1.